# Quando uso PathParam ou QueryParam?

Tags: web-service, api

Eu sei a diferença, porém quando eu faço uso do PathParam ou QueryParam? É correto a seguinte explicação?

> If there is a scenario to retrieve a record based on id, for example
>   you need to get the details of the employee whose id is 15, then you
>   can have resource with @PathParam.

`GET /employee/{id}`

> If there is a scenario where you need to get the details of all employees but only 10 at a time, you may use query param

```
GET /employee?start=1&size=10
```

Comment: Isso não é algo nativo do Java, certo? Assumi dada [essa pergunta semelhante no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5579744/520779) que se trata da framework Jersey, mas se eu estiver enganado favor reverter minha edição.

Comment: Obrigada, fiz a correção! A tag correta é "web-service"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5580361/520779), `PathParam` serve para acessar o caminho enquanto `QueryParam` serve para acessar a *query string*. Esclarecendo, uma URL completa* possui as seguintes partes:

```
http    :// google.com : 80    /foo/bar/baz ?a=10&b=20     #seção

esquema :// origem     : porta caminho      query_string   fragmento
```

Não conheço o Jersey, então não posso dizer quando é apropriado usar um ou outro, exceto que depende de onde a informação que você quer está (no caminho ou na *query string*). Do ponto de vista do REST, o mais comum é colocar nomes e ids de recursos no próprio caminho, enquanto parâmetros de buscas arbitrárias podem vir na *query string* - de modo que considero correta a explicação citada.

* Bem, *quase* completa: ainda é possível ter `usuario:senha@` antes da origem, mas nunca vi isso sendo usado na prática...

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi explicado pelo @mgibsonbr, cada anotação lê os parâmetros de locais diferentes.

Porém, é importante compreender que o framework Jersey implementa a API JAX-RS, que é a API padrão do Java para **RESTful Web Services**. Portanto o correto é seguir sempre os padrões da arquitetura REST.

Nesse caso a explicação está correta, pois no REST entende-se que os identificadores de recursos ficam no caminho da URL, identificando aquele recurso de forma única.

Se o empregado (*employee*) é um recurso do sistema, então é correto acessá-lo pela requisição `GET /employee/{id}.`

Parâmetros adicionais, exemplificados na pergunta como dados de paginação, são passados como parâmetros de URL porque são informações secundárias.